# How to add an image upload field in a custom Field Type

Tags: entities, 8, media

I'm defining a new custom Field Type in Drupal 8, let's say `MyFieldType`, with custom widget and formatter also.

Such Field Type should have these two fields:

- `text`: a simple text value
- `image`: a field where the user that use this Field Type can upload an image, as the [built-in image field type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!ImageItem.php/class/ImageItem/8).

I created the custom field type with the `text` field with no problems. Now I'm trying to add the `image` field also, but I'm stuck and I don't understand how to proceed.

What is the correct way to add an image upload field in a custom Field Type?

---

### What I tried

Below there are the main parts from the custom Field Type. All files are from the folder `modules\custom\my_field_type\src\Plugin\Field`.

From the file `FieldType\MyFieldType.php`:

```php
class MyFieldType extends FieldItemBase {

  //

  public static function propertyDefinitions(
    FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition
  ) {

    $properties['text'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
        ->setLabel(t('Text Value'));

    // $properties['image'] ... go here?
    // ...

    return $properties;
  }

  //

  public static function schema(
    FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition
  ) {

    $columns = array(

      'text' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
      ),

      // What column for the 'image' field?
      // ...

    );

    $schema = array(
      'columns' => $columns,
    );

    return $schema;
  }

}
```

From the file `FieldWidget\MyFieldTypeWidget.php`:

```php
class MyFieldTypeWidget extends WidgetBase {

  public function formElement(
    FieldItemListInterface $items,
    $delta, 
    Array $element, 
    Array &$form, 
    FormStateInterface $formState
  ) {

    $element['value'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Value'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->value) ? 
          $items[$delta]->value : null,
      '#empty_value' => '',
    ];

    $element['image'] = [
      '#type' => 'file',
      '#title' => t('Image'),

      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->image) ? 
        $items[$delta]->image : null,

      '#empty_value' => '',
    ];

    return $element;
  }

}
```

I can see the file upload field in the edit form (adding a new field with this custom type), but I don't know how to go on and (eventually) how to handle the uploaded image inside the class `MyFieldType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do, is to save a reference to the file which is uploaded.

Since what you are making is an image upload with extra text field, you should consider using either

- `\Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget`
- `\Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\FileWidget`

as foundation to your widget. That way you should be able to reuse much of the trick image/file handling and just add custom parts or overrides for your custom widget.

You should also consider using either

- `\Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem`
- `Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileItem`

as foundation to your field type, since they also handle a lot of things for you. The image variant adds a lot of stuff, like alt, height, width, which is something you probably want/need at some point, so no reason making all of this yourself.